# MySQL 5.7 - group by with having not working

Tags: mysql, group-by, mysql-error-1055

I'm using MySQL 5.7 and have a query below:

```
SELECT 
    U.*,
    C.country,
    C.id AS country_id,
    C.iso
FROM 
    `users` AS U
LEFT JOIN
    `countries` AS C
ON 
    U.user_country_id = C.id
WHERE
    U.user_deleted = 0
GROUP BY
    U.user_country_id
HAVING 
    MAX(U.user_credits)
```

The problem is:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'dbname.U.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;

I can't change my group (wrong results) to: **GROUP BY U.user_country_id, U.id**

How can I change my request the right way?
Thanks!

Comment: You want obtain  the row that have the user_credits = max(user_credits) ?

Comment: What's the scheme of the tables and what do you want to obtain? Have you considered to put the group by in a nested query?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the row with the max(U.user_credits) this way

```
SELECT 
    U.*,
    C.country,
    C.id AS country_id,
    C.iso
FROM 
    `users` AS U
LEFT JOIN
    `countries` AS C
ON 
    U.user_country_id = C.id
WHERE
   U.user_deleted = 0
AND   U.user_credits = ( select max(U.user_credits) from `users` as U)
```

Comment: Your query returns me just one row.

Comment: @user889349  . of course .. if you need a different solution  update your question adding proper data sample and expected  result  ..